# How can void main return 0?

Tags: c, visual-studio

```
void main()
{
    printf("hi\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Why does the compiler give no error when I'm returning a value from the function main with return type void?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?  `gcc` would emit a warning in this case, something like `'return' ..., in a function returning void`.

Comment: If you have warnings turned on, it would yield a warning. When compiled with `gcc` I get: `warning: ‘return’ with a value, in function returning void [enabled by default]`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c?rq=1

Comment: A better question is how can `main` be declared as void in the first place? Any return type other than `int` is non-standard and really just doesn't make sense for `main`.

Answer (score 1):

No. It can't. You are doing wrong. You can't return anything from a function whose return type is `void`. Your compiler should give a warning:

```
[Warning] 'return' with a value, in function returning void [enabled by default]
```

`void main` is obsolete now.  The standard says about the definition of `main`.

#### 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup:

> 1 The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no
>   prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no
>   parameters:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be
>   used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent;10) or in some other implementation-defined manner.

Comment: Its ok..I know it is obsolete. But shouldnt it give me an error?

Answer (score 0):

Main is special.

Strictly speaking it should be

```
int main(int, char**);
```

If you deviate from that (such as by using `void`), the compiler will likely throw a warning (if you have warnings turned on) but produce valid code anyway.

EDIT: Apparently `int main()` is also valid.

Comment: How to turn on warnings in Visual Studio? (if you can help)
Also, what if I lose on such questions in my aptitude tests or interviews because of compiler differences? whose fault is it? mine or different compilers'?

Comment: It would appear you don't want them *all*: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001736/what-with-the-thousands-of-warnings-in-standard-headers-in-msvc-wall -- but http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/edzzzth4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx may help you

Answer (score 0):

Either you are, or your compiler is, doing something wrong. You can't return a value from a void function. The compiler should emit a warning, at the least.