# Eigen "'__CUDACC_VER__' is not defined" warning

Tags: c++, eigen

I get the below compiler warning in Visual Studio C++ Community 2015 with Eigen linear algebra library version 3.3.2. Any ideas why this could be happening, or what I should be checking?

eigen\src/Core/util/Macros.h(815): warning C4668: '**CUDACC_VER**' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif'

Comment: How about posting some code?

Comment: just  "#include <Eigen/Dense>" is enough to trip the warning

Comment: It is best to share the code. Looks like you have some issues with you code.

Comment: Fixed https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/commits/ec1a83756f00/

Comment: Thank you @ggael.

Answer (score 0):

If you look up the [warning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4dt9kyhy.aspx) you will see that

```
#if SOME_NAME
```

will cause a warning if `SOME_NAME` is not defined. The `replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif` actually *is* the desired behavior. You can get rid of the warning by changing the code to `defined(__CUDACC_VER__)`

Note: You received this warning because you have a high (`/W4` or `/Wall`) in your project. While this is usually a good thing, [often](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001736/whats-up-with-the-thousands-of-warnings-in-standard-headers-in-msvc-wall) with VS it kinda defeats the purpose (signal to noise ratio being too low).