# Treat all warnings of specific level as errors but not those of next level

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2017, compiler-warnings

I know [there is `/WX` to treat all warnings as errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level). And there is `/we1234` to treat a specific warning (i.e. 1234) as an error.

What I miss is a flag to treat all warnings of level 3 as errors but not those of level 4.

In my legacy project we just managed to get rid of all W3 warnings and increased to W4. As this raised a couple thousands warnings, we will not be able to spot any new warnings of W3 when being introduced.
Thus we want to make all W3 warnings errors.

I could compile a list of all W3 warnings and add a `/weXYZ` for each of them, but this seems way too tedious.

Comment: `W4` would always trigger zillions of warnings from STL implementation.

Comment: @Zereges I can not confirm. I'm mostly getting warnings from our code with VS2017. This was true for <=VS2015.

Comment: Interesting point, another reason for upgrading :)

Comment: @Zereges W4 [should be okay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001736/whats-up-with-the-thousands-of-warnings-in-standard-headers-in-msvc-wall) but Wall will get the zillions of errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of choices:

Either add a `/weXYZ` for each level three warning.  Do this as follows:

- Add a couple of such flags through the GUI
- Open the project file in a text editor, and find the format it uses
- Scrape a list of all the level three warnings from a suitable webpage
- Edit it into the correct format
- Put the settings into the project file.

Alternatively, rather than enabling *all* level 4 warnings, enable them one at a time (once you have fixed the previous ones).

Comment: A `.vsprops` file would be more useful, as it would be reusable.

Comment: I'm using CMake to generate the project and solution files. So I'll not going to add anything through the VS GUI. You'r basically describing my last sentence of my question.