# Google Mock: Mocked overloaded functions create warning C4373

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mocking, overloading, googlemock

I'm mocking a C++ class which has 2 overloaded functions using [Google Mock](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/) and VS2010:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

#include "A.h"

class MockA : public A
{
public:
    // ...
    MOCK_METHOD3(myFunc, void(const int id, const int errorCode, const CString errorMsg));
    MOCK_METHOD1(myFunc, void(const CString errorMsg));
    // ...
};
```

Each time I compile I get the following warning twice:

```
1>c:\dev\my_project\tests\mocka.h(83): warning C4373: 'MockA::myFunc': virtual function overrides 'A::myFunc', previous versions of the compiler did not override when parameters only differed by const/volatile qualifiers
1>          c:\dev\my_project\my_project\include\a.h(107) : see declaration of 'A::myFunc'
```

Any idea why?
Is this correct behavior?
How can I avoid this?

Comment: Make sure you're using the right variant -- MOCK_CONST_METHOD should be used when `A`'s method you're overriding is `const`.

Comment: @Billy ONeal - The method itself is not const, only its parameters are. Should I still use MOCK_CONST_METHOD ?

Comment: No; in that case you should do what you are doing :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If this is new code, you should be fine.  The [C4373 warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-3-c4373) is saying that old versions of Visual Studio violated the standard. From the linked documentation:

> Versions of the compiler prior to
>   Visual C++ 2008 bind the function to
>   the method in the base class, then
>   issue a warning message. Subsequent
>   versions of the compiler ignore the
>   const or volatile qualifier, bind the
>   function to the method in the derived
>   class, then issue warning C4373. This
>   latter behavior complies with the C++
>   standard.

This would only be a problem if you had broken code that relied on Visual Studio's incorrect behavior.

Comment: I sure hope you're right. Do you have a reference to back this up? Somewhere people discussing this is indeed past false behavior? Also - how then can I mute this specific warning?

Comment: @Jon, it's explained in the link.  Note the last part, "This latter behavior complies with the C++ standard."

Comment: thanks. I used the following to suppress the warning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541984/how-to-suppress-warnings-in-external-headers-in-visual-c

Comment: I don't understand, all `const` are in right places. And anyway the warning has been fired, and why only for some subset of  methods?

Answer (score 8):

For me (in VS 2010), specifying the `const` on primitive type parameters (which I see you also have) caused this behavior. Whenever such existed in the base class function I wanted to override, I couldn't specify the mock in a way so that this warning did not occur; when only having class type const value / const reference parameters, the warning never occured.

So to me it seems like the warning in that case is actually a mistake in the compiler (as the signatures are exactly the same).

Comment: I had the error exactly in this case (const qualifier for a primitive). VS 2015 and gmock.1.10.0. Removing the const solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested alternative approach:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

#include "A.h"

class MockA : public A
{
public:
    // ...

    void myFunc(const int id, const int errorCode, const CString errorMsg) {
      mocked_myFunc3(id, errorCode, errorMsg);
    }

    void myFunc(const CString errorMsg) {
      mocked_myFunc1(errorMsg);
    }

    MOCK_METHOD3(mocked_myFunc_3, void(const int id, const int errorCode, const CString errorMsg));
    MOCK_METHOD1(mocked_myFunc_1, void(const CString errorMsg));
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is an old question, but since I stumbled upon it myself now, I'd like to share my solution (or at least explanation):

The problem is likely that your *declaration* has a const parameter, which will be ignored by the compiler. It is the *definition* that may effectively use const for the parameter.

It's also mentioned now in the [google mock faq](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/gmock_faq.md#msvc-gives-me-warning-c4301-or-c4373-when-i-define-a-mock-method-with-a-const-parameter-why) now that, in order to get rid of the warning, remove `const` from the parameter in the function declaration.

In my case I found it still hard since the function implementation was for a templated class inside a header where declaration and definition happen are both done together. Solution to that is probably to disable the warning when including the mocked class' header.