# Vs2008: Disable warnings in included header files outside the project

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Is it possible? I don't want to disable the warning globally as I want to check my own header files for warnings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to suppress warnings in external headers in Visual C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541984/how-to-suppress-warnings-in-external-headers-in-visual-c)

Answer (score 4):

You can disable warnings around the include of the external header file:

```
#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning( disable: the warning)
 // include here
#pragma warning( pop )
```

If you need to include the header multiple times, you can create a header with the pragmas and include that instead. 
The same question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541984/how-to-suppress-warnings-in-external-headers-in-visual-c).