# Suppress warnings for external headers in VS2017 Code Analysis

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2017, static-analysis

I want to use the Code Analysis in Visual Studio 2017 but I'm using Qt and it gives me a lot of warnings from the headers. I've tried turning off warnings:

```
#pragma warning(push, 0)
#include <QtGlobal>
#pragma warning(pop)
```

but it doesn't help. I also tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191479/how-do-i-exclude-library-headers-from-my-visual-studio-static-code-analysis):

```
#include <codeanalysis\warnings.h>
#pragma warning(push, 0)
#pragma warning(disable : ALL_CODE_ANALYSIS_WARNINGS)
#include <QtGlobal>
#pragma warning(pop)
```

but no help. How can I disable the Code Analysis for the Qt external headers?

Comment: But that will disable the warnings on the entire codebase. I just want it to ignore external headers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you open your .vcxproj file, down the bottom you should see:

```
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
```

below this you can add:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Language)'=='C++'">
    <IncludePath>$(QTDIR)\include;.\GeneratedFiles;$(IncludePath)</IncludePath>
    <CAExcludePath>$(QTDIR)\include;.\GeneratedFiles;$(CAExcludePath)</CAExcludePath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Microsoft say there's a bug where `CAExcludePath` is overwritten by `IncludePath` but this is fixed in [Visual Studio 2017 V15.3](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/) and you'll only need to set `CAExcludePath` - I haven't verified this (I'll update this once I do).

This answer came from [How can I suppress warnings for external headers in VS2017 Code Analysis?](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/68319/how-can-i-suppress-warnings-for-external-headers-i-1.html)

Comment: Tried this solution, but this is not working for me. I see that CAExcludePath is set correctly, but I still get warnings from compilation of 3rd party headers. I'm using version 15.2 (26430.6) Release. Also tried to set CAExcludePath in Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Targets, no success.

Comment: Also, you can drop this into a property sheet as a "user macro". I found that I needed to check the box that says "Set this macro as an environment variable in the build environment".

Comment: You don't need <IncludePath> as far as I can tell. I've just disabled warnings for boost this way in VS 15.7.