# Enable Visual Studio's C++ Core Check analysis only on project files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am a big fan of the [C++ Core Guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) and I like to follow them in all projects I work on, so I enabled the following option in my project template in `Visual Studio 2017`:

[image: The C++ Core Check project option]

This tool is great and helps me write better code, but I simply cannot figure out how to make it only analyze **my files**. Whenever my project has a dependency such as [Boost](https://www.boost.org/) or [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/), I will get plastered with a wall of warnings:

[image: C++ Core Check warnings on dependencies]

These dependencies are added through [vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg), however, the same thing happens when adding them manually with `C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories`.

Is there any way to only make these warnings apply to project files, and not all included files?

Comment: Did you see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44640171/9478968)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, right after the following section in your `.vcxproj` near the end of the file:

```
<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
</ImportGroup>
```

The problem may be solved by adding the following after the section mentioned above:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Language)'=='C++'">
  <CAExcludePath>$(QTDIR)\include;.\GeneratedFiles;$(CAExcludePath)</CAExcludePath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Furthermore, if you are using [vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg), which was the case in my situation, you will need to add the following element to the `CAExcludePath`:

```
$(VcpkgRoot)include
```

This will ensure that all headers from any packages will not be analyzed.

Comment: Not sure why you have `QTDIR` there. This seems like it comes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44640171/9478968, but that question was tagged `qt`. This question isn't.