# How to add Property to Affect Code Analysis in CMake

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2019

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44640171/10686048), I've added the below code to my `.vcxproj` file, which nicely eliminates most warnings that I was getting from Qt include files, and its autogenerated moc files.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Language)'=='C++'">
  <CAExcludePath>C:\Qt\5.13.1\msvc2017_64\include;.\ProjectName_autogen;$(CAExcludePath)</CAExcludePath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This is great for one specific project, but since I use CMake, on multiple computers, this would get overwritten each time the CMake file changes, and I would have to add it to each Project I need it for (there's 3 projects that use Qt). Of course, the issue is also if I change the Qt path, then I would need to update the project files as well.

I am wondering, is there a CMake property I can set in order to add this to the projects? I know how to get Qt's include directory, just looking for the CMake property to actually set the `CAExcludePath`. If it helps, I'm using VS 2019, and this is to disable the warnings from Code Analysis.

I did check the [cmake-properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#manual:cmake-properties(7)) page, but didn't find any predefined properties which seem to fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. For anyone interested, I created a file called `user.props` which looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Language)'=='C++'">
    <CAExcludePath>@QWT_INCLUDE_DIR@;@QT_INCLUDE_DIR@;.;$(CAExcludePath)</CAExcludePath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Then, in the `CMakeList.txt` root file, I have

```
SET( RULESET_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/user.props )
CONFIGURE_FILE(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/user.props ${RULESET_PATH} @ONLY)
```

Then for each project I want to apply it to, I have

```
SET_PROPERTY( TARGET "ProjectName" PROPERTY VS_USER_PROPS "${RULESET_PATH}" )
```

There might be a more direct way, but this works.