# Disable Warnings from Google Test

Tags: c++, visual-studio, googletest

I have just installed a fresh Visual Studio 16.10.3 and added `Google Test` to my command console app. Right of the bat, I get the following warnings:

| Severity | Code | Description | Project | File | Line | Suppression State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Warning | C26812 | The enum type 'testing::TestPartResult::Type' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3). | Tests | D:\C++\ConsoleTest\packages\Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn.1.8.1.4\build\native\include\gtest\gtest-test-part.h | 62 |  |
| Warning | C26495 | Variable 'testing::internal::Mutex::critical_section_' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). | Tests | D:\C++\ConsoleTest\packages\Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn.1.8.1.4\build\native\include\gtest\internal\gtest-port.h | 1804 |  |
| Warning | C26495 | Variable 'testing::internal::Mutex::critical_section_init_phase_' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). | Tests | D:\C++\ConsoleTest\packages\Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn.1.8.1.4\build\native\include\gtest\internal\gtest-port.h | 1804 |  |
| Warning | C26495 | Variable 'testing::internal::Mutex::owner_thread_id_' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). | Tests | D:\C++\ConsoleTest\packages\Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn.1.8.1.4\build\native\include\gtest\internal\gtest-port.h | 1804 |  |
| Warning | C26495 | Variable 'testing::internal::Mutex::type_' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). | Tests | D:\C++\ConsoleTest\packages\Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn.1.8.1.4\build\native\include\gtest\internal\gtest-port.h | 1804 |  |
| Warning | C26812 | The enum type 'testing::internal::Mutex::StaticConstructorSelector' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3). | Tests | D:\C++\ConsoleTest\packages\Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn.1.8.1.4\build\native\include\gtest\internal\gtest-port.h | 1804 |  |

I tried suppressing the warnings by surrounding `#include "pch.h"` [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541984/how-to-suppress-warnings-in-external-headers-in-visual-c):

```
#pragma warning(push, 0)  
#include "pch.h"
#pragma warning(pop)
```

However, that didn't work - instead, I only got an additional warning that

> #pragma warning(pop): no matching '#pragma warning(push)' (C4193)

I also read the [Broken Warnings Theory](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/broken-warnings-theory/). Unfortunately, I have to admit that I do not understand it. I think this is the relevant section:

> To suppress the warning in external headers, we need to both specify which headers are external and what the warning level in those headers should be:
>
> cl.exe /experimental:external /external:I some_lib_dir /external:W0 /W4 my_prog.cpp
>
> This would effectively get rid of any warning inside some_hdr.hpp while preserving warnings inside my_prog.cpp.

But where would I add these switches and what would be the correct path variable for googletest?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You have to specify the warning number which you want to suppress here: `#pragma warning(push, 26812) ` And do this directly in the pch file

Comment: Maybe, as another option, you could compile your test files separately (without warnings) and link together everything?

Comment: with gcc you can include them as system headers via `-isystem` to silence warnings, though not sure whats the VS equiavlent

Comment: @RoQuOTriX: Sadly, that did not work and, despite what I said earlier, moving it to "pch.h" also did not have any effect.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

> suppressing the warnings by surrounding `#include "pch.h"`

you should use the `warning` pragma to surround both header files(`gtest-port.h` and `gtest-test-part.h`), which can be found in `External Dependencies` in `Solution Explorer` of the Visual Studio project. The detailed methods are as below.

- Add the following code to the very beginning and end of `gtest-port.h`

  ```
  #pragma warning( push )
  #pragma warning( disable : 26495 )
  #pragma warning( disable : 26812 )

  // Original Code

  #pragma warning( pop )
  ```
- Similarly, add the following code to the very beginning and end of `gtest-test-part.h`

  ```
  #pragma warning( push )
  #pragma warning( disable : 26812 )

  // Original Code

  #pragma warning( pop )
  ```