# VS17 Intellisense Warns on "Deferencing NULL pointer" from many WxWidgets header file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, wxwidgets

I get these warning from VS17, mainly on dereferencing NULL point m_node.

```
Warning C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'm_node'.    window.h
Warning C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'm_node'.    any.h
Warning C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'm_node'.    dataobj.h
Warning C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'm_node'.    gdicmn.h
Warning C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'm_node'.    list.h
Warning C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'm_node'.    list.h
Warning C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'm_node'.    menu.h
Warning C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'm_node'.    menu.h
Warning C26495  Variable 'wxModule::m_state' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    module.h
Warning C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'm_node'.    gdiimage.h
Warning C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'm_node'.    sizer.h
Warning C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'm_node'.    tbarbase.h
Warning C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'm_node'.    variant.h
```

I try to isolate the project files but they seem to persistence, from wxwidgets library.

I have no issue compiling the code and running them.

This warning is generated by the IntelliSense as I set the Error List on "Built+IntelliSense".

It was clustering the Error List and I want to switch off the warning from IntelliSense and to rely on the Build only.

However I'm not sure that this is good habit unless this is a known issue with wxWidgets library and I just have to accept them and rely on the Build only.

Can I get educated on this?

Comment: You can configure VS to ignore external headers like those for code analysis warnings.

Comment: @ChrisMM that right, I should do that using "#pragma warning (push)", 
"#pragma warning (disable: 1234 5678 ...)", & "#pragma warning (pop)". Thanks for suggestion. But is this a common issue with wxWidgets? If they are common, I sure will ignore the warning.

Comment: I was more referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47934690/10686048). I've done this before (though differently, I edited the .vcxproj file) when using Qt in the past. I've not used wxWidgets though.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisMM. Somebody would come and say their view on the wxWidgets aspects sooner or later.

Answer (score 2):

These are code analysis warnings which are harmless and many of them are simply false positives. wxWidgets headers compile without real (compiler) warnings at maximum warning level, but you do have to exclude them if you're using the code analysis, suppressing all the bogus warnings is just not worth it.

Comment: Nice! Thank @VZ.

Comment: Thanks @VZ. Now I know, I can just those warning in the ignore list everytime I have the wx headers.